# Как в DetailView сделать строки с заголовками (одна ячейка, а не две)?

Tags: php, yii2

В *DetailView* в своей дефолтной реализации всё выводится парами ключ->значение.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
   'model' => $model,
   'attributes' => [
       'id',
       [
        'label' => 'test',
        'value' => 'test',        
       ],
   ],
]) ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как, что и где нужно прописать, чтобы я мог логически отделить группы полей неким заголовком? Чтобы было вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd. Для реализации "одной цельной строки"  пока написал так:

```
   [
       'label' => 'Секция каких-то данных',
       'value' => '',
       'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'd-none'],
       'captionOptions' => ['colspan' => 2],
   ],
```

но  наверное это как-то неправильно

Comment: Сделать таблицу и вставить виджеты детальные в нужные ячейки с нужными данными.

Comment: @fedornabilkin это не костыльно?) если этих секций, допустим, 10?) Более простых способов, например за счет указания класса css или опции нет?)

Comment: Тут вопрос в другом, будет ли 10 запросов на 10 секций? Если да, то данные надо будет кешировать или вообще отказаться от этого виджета. На самом деле польза от него так себе.